# Is there a logic where variables can have more than two values but "truth values" are still binary (either "false" or "true")?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

In the standard propositional logic we have a certain number of variables (let's say A, B, C, D, E, and F) which can take one of two values (0 or 1, False or True). If we know the values of each variable (let's say A = 0, B = 1, C = 1, D = 0, and so on), then we know everything about the "world" and we do not need logic. However, instead of a complete knowledge about the world (value of each variable) we might have some restrictions like: We do not know what values A, B and C have, but we know that either A and B are both equal to 1 or C is not equal to 1: $(A \land B) \lor (\lnot C)$. In addition to that we usualy have some other "restrictions" (for example $\lnot A \land (\lnot D \land B)$, and so on). The goal of the propositional logic is to combine those "restrictions" to say what the world can / can't be.

This picture naturally suggest a generalisation. What if our variables (A, B, C, D, and so on) can have more than two values? Let's say instead of allowing them to be "black" and "white" (as before), we allow them be "red", "green" and "blue". Is there a special logic for that? Within this logic we could make statements like this: If B is blue or green, then A is red, except C is black (in this case A is blue or yellow).

Is there a special logic for statements like this? Many-valued logic is the first what comes in mind, but I guess it is about allowing truth-values to have more than two values, which is not the same as the case I have described.

Comment: You want the variables to have a domain of more than two values, but you don't want more than two truth values? So you don't want the variable's values to be truth values? Then you're not looking for any propositional logic at all, because in propositional logic, variable's values *are* truth values. I assume you do know about first-order logic, where what you describe can be expressed a e.g. $Blue(a) \lor Green(a) \land \neg White(b)$? What's wrong with using that

Comment: @lemontree, FOL seems to be much more expressive than I need. First, it looks like the logic that I describe do not use any variables (only constants referring to specific (coloured) object). Second, I need to use only predicates with arity 1. Third, I do not use quantifiers. Fourth, FOL do not have the notions that values (colours in my case) are mutually exclusive.

Comment: I am with lemontree .. when you ask "What if our variables (A, B, C, D, and so on) can have more than two values?" but then later say "Many-valued logic is the first what comes in mind, but I guess it is about allowing truth-values to have more than two values, which is not the same as the case I have described." you seem to be just contradicting yourself: you want variables to be able to have one of more than two possible values and yet you don't?

Comment: @Bram28, contradiction is resolved by the fact, that I do not want to treat variables as propositions anymore. But I still want to use Boolean operations to make statements about my variables (like in the example I gave).

Comment: Ah, so then what Lemontree later says applies: you are then simply not doing logic anymore, but some other kind of abstract algebra ... which also means that you would have to specify what the 'boolean operations' do. E.g. If variable $A$ evaluates to "blue", then $\neg A$ would be "orange", etc. So how you want to dedfine those is up to you ... it all depends on how you want to use this system ... what kinds of things you wan it to represent/describe ... and what the operations mean.

Comment: You can accomplish this with many-valued logic, where you view these values in a binary fashion: either the formula is false, or it is not false (but without necessarily being true). A truth value in many valued logic simply carries varied degrees of information, and simply having a truth value which is not false is enough to give you a satisfying model (or world, as you call it).

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note is that there is not actually a widely accepted definition of what counts as a "Logic". The closest thing to that is [Gurevich's definition](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9705225.pdf), which is what I will be using to answer your question. I paraphrase it as follows. A *logic* $L$ is given by a pair of functions (Sen,Sat) satisfying the following conditions. Sen associates with every vocabulary $\sigma$ a recursive set Sen($\sigma$) whose elements are called $L$-*sentences of vocabulary* $\sigma$. Sat associates with every vocabulary $\sigma$ a recursive relation Sat$_\sigma(A,\varphi)$ where $A$ is a $\sigma$-structure and $\varphi$  an $L$-sentence of vocabulary $\sigma$. We say that $A$ satisfies $\varphi$ if Sat$_\sigma(A,\varphi)$ holds.

Unpacking this, Sen is meant to be the set of all sentences of the logic, and Sat determines whether a structure satisfies that sentence. As an example, there is an easy definition for Sen and Sat that give propositional logic, setting Sen($\tau$) to be the set of all propositional sentences with up to $k$ distinct propositions, where $\tau$ is some vocabulary of $k$ distinct propositions, and setting Sat($A,\varphi$) to be the function that verifies whether the assignment of the propositions given by $A$ satisfies $\varphi$. For all other vocabularies $\sigma$, Sen($\sigma$) gets the empty set.

Notice here that the binary-ness of propositional calculus comes from the fact that we take as convention that propositions are nullary relations. So these vocabularies $b_k$ are merely sets of $k$ nullary relations. Thus, there is no analagous version for what you're looking for under the classical definition of relations, and hence under this definition of logics. You can of course generalize the definition of vocabulary so that instead of a vocabulary having only a set of relations and functions within its universe, it also has a set of functions with co-domain some fixed boolean algebra, that's how you get many-valued logics.

There is really no good way to enforce what you are looking for, the best you can do is something similar to what follows. Define the vocabulary $\sigma$ to have unary relations $Red(x), Blue(x), Green(x),$etc. and $k$ constants $P_1,P_2,\ldots,P_k$ to represent the propositions, for some $k$. Then you can define Sen($\sigma$) to be the boolean formulas over $\sigma$ (where base terms are in the form $R(P_i)$, where $R$ is some relation in $\sigma$). For any $\sigma$-structure $A$ and any $L$-sentence $\varphi$, Sat($A,\varphi$) will be true if and only if $A$ satisfies $\varphi$ in the typical way and moreover, $A$ interprets the relations of $\sigma$ to form a partition over the constants $P_i$. That is, for any two relations $R_\ell,R_j \in \sigma$, $R_\ell \cap R_j = \emptyset$ and for some $j$, $P_i \in R_j$. This no longer satisfies some of the basic tautologies you find in boolean logic however, for example the sentence $Red(P)\vee\neg Red(P)$ will no longer be a tautology. To make that a tautology you would have to restrict the class of structures over which we consider the logic, but this does not count as a logic of its own.

Comment: The link contains the promised definition at the top of p. 9.